# How to prevent crash if value in DataGridView cell is NaN, or restrict user until there is a value in cell?

Tags: c#, validation, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I have a DataGridview in which the first column the user inputs a value, and the second column computes an answer, both are then plotted on a chart.

Currently the values in the second column are computed after pressing a "compute button".

However if the user presses the button before they have input any values in the first cells of the first column, the computed values in the cells of the second column come out as "NaN" and the application crashes when the code below runs or if code below is removed the crashes at "Generate Chart button"?

I'm new to C# and programming overall so I'm not sure how to prevent this from happening, perhaps somehow through validation.

This is what I've currently tried (code below), however I get a "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range."

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in this.dataGridView3.Rows)
            {
                for (int G = 0; G < rw.Cells.Count; G++)
                {
                    if (rw.Cells[G].Value == null || rw.Cells[G].Value == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rw.Cells[G].Value.ToString()) || double.IsNaN(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[G].Cells[1].Value)))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please compute Vulnerabiltiy Curve Points!");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        chart1.Series["V-curve"].Points.AddXY(dataGridView3.Rows[G].Cells[1].Value, dataGridView3.Rows[G].Cells[0].Value);

                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Check your `if` statement. You are using your *Cell* index `G` as a *Row* index: `dataGridView1.Rows[G].Cells[1].Value`  That should explain your `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Overall, instead of looping through the cells in each row, I would assume you know exactly which cells the user needs to have filled in before calculating?  If so, just validate that each of them is filled in - and if not show your MessageBox.  As is, you are going to show a MessageBox *for every empty cell*. --Oh, and welcome to the world of programming! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, and warm welcome, I see where my mistake was now, I wanted to ask you, if I set up an "if" statement at the compute button, to validate if each one is filled in, I know the column in which the cells that need to be filled are in, however each user will have a different number of rows in that column, hence why I thought looping might be the way, but normally how do you validate each cell, is that through one of the inbuilt events of the cell? thanks

Comment: Normally if you want to validate user input after the user enters it you would look at the [`CellValidating`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating?view=netframework-4.8) event and handle the cell according to the column rule you want for it.  For your purpose, your way seems fine.  I'd loop through each row but then if-check only the necessary cells of each row.